# What is David Milch talking about?

Tags: listening

There is an interview from David Milch - the creator of the TV series "Deadwood". At the final part, he said ( seems ):" All of those things for me remind me as I sort of lived into the story that the reason is about 17th on a list of the attributes that ??defines us?? as a species and as far as I'm concerned they can lower no problem a I just like to see the way we behave.".

I have no idea what he means by "17th on a list of the attributes that.." I might have heard it wrong. (as I typed above)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1O2GW9G1h5A

(PS. the transcript seems incorrect but I paste here as reference anyway)
all of those things
for me remind me as a shorter lived in to this story
a that reason is about seventeen
analyst the attributes that the finances
as a species)

I also deeply wonder who transcribe the whole text for this video. If  it's robot, it's too accurate. If it's human, it's amazingly incorrect. Maybe one time speedy catch-up deal).

Comment: It's probably a [stenographer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand) using a [stenotype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenotype).

Comment: If you give a location on the video (e.g. ~19 min. in), we might be able to help you better?

Comment: 27:46, this is where it is.

Comment: Stenographer? Cool! I tried actually using a voice recognition software because I suspect that is what it is plus Google can do crazy stuff. And it failed - very wrong because of the ambient sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that what he actually said was "all of those things, for me, remind me as I sort of lived into the story that *reason is about 17th on a list of the attributes that define us as a species*."  If so, what he probably meant was that there are many things more central to human nature than reason.

Please also note that *about 17* is probably just being used as an indicator of a generic large number.